# Spa pump wont run when in spa

Tags: water, electric-motor

Spa pump motor won't run when its in the spa. I removed the pump and ran power to it and it runs fine. Also, with the pump removed, turned on spa jets and no problems. So, re-installed the pump and when turned on, I hear a buzzing sound for say 30 seconds and it trips the breaker. Any ideas please help, and thank you!

Comment: Did you just remove the pump motor, or the entire pump? If only the motor, can you turn the pump (the part attached to the motor) by hand? If you cannot, there's your issue. Something is binding the motor and not allowing it to run. This would be the first place I'd look.

Comment: I agree with Paulster. It sounds like the motor is good, but the pump is stuck. The motor can't spin the pump, which causes it to draw a very high current and trip the breaker. Usually there's fuses in place, to protect the motor from this type of situation. The idea is that the fuse will blow before the motor burns up.

Comment: These kind of motors usually include a "start" capacitor that can go bad and prevent the motor from starting under load

Answer (score 1):

A few possibilities -

- **The pump is frozen but the motor works** - The motor cannot turn the
  pump.  With the motor off of the pump, the pump is difficult to turn. - Fix the pump
- **3 phase motor driven with just 2 of the legs** - something is disconnected somewhere - I've had this issues with a loose/melted wire nut on a motor with large pump that had this same issue. - Fix wiring
- **The motor works without load, but is not able to work with load.**  Testing is tricky - try other possibilities first - problem could be motor, but more likely the driving circuits.